# Wordpress versions 5.3 and 5.4

Tags: wordpress

I am testing Wordpress website that is in 5.3.3 version, which is current and updated just few days ago (April 29, 2020). But there is also 5.4 branch, is it recommended to upgrade to 5.4 because it seems to be supported longer?

List of Wordpress versions: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They tell you that only the latest branch is secure because as far as I know there is no official policy for supporting old versions. That means that support for old branches is not guaranteed. In practice however, you can see that they are still providing patches for version 3.7, which was originally released in 2013, and got last patched a week ago in version 3.7.33.

So while in theory you should upgrade to branch 5.4 as soon as it comes out, in practice you can keep your 5.3 version as long as you install the patches (5.3.1, 5.3.2, etc.), which should get installed automatically by default anyway (some kind of internal cron provided by WordPress). The risk of WordPress actually dropping support for a recent branch is almost non-existent, in my opinion. Older branches are more at risk of course.

Answer (score 2):

From the [releases page](https://wordpress.org/download/releases/):

> None of these are safe to use, except the **latest** in the 5.4 series,
>   which is actively maintained.

From the changelog, it looks like 5.3.3 contained some minor security fixes and other maintenance updates. But unless you have a strong reason not to upgrade, it is probably best to follow their recommendation to use the latest version.